Помогите исправить рандомайзер
очевидно проблема в 3 строчке, но как её исправить?
я совсем не разбираюсь в рандомайзерах,
import random
random1 = int (input("Enter 1 number:"))
random2 = int (input("Enter 2 number:"))
print(random(random1,random2))


Ку, если хочешь использовать число от и до используй этот код:
import random
random1 = int(input('Enter 1 number:'))
random2 = int(input('Enter 2 number:'))
print(random.randint(random1, random2))

random - это модуль, randint - его функция в его классе. Еще можно использовать так:
from random import randint
random1 = int(input('Enter 1 number:'))
random2 = int(input('Enter 2 number:'))
print(randint(random1, random2))

